# Input type"file" styling with "jQuery FileStyle" and jQuery clone()

Tags: jquery, input

I have a simple form for file upload. It's styled with the jQuery FileStyle plugin.  I have button for clone input field. After clone() each new object isn`t styled with filestyle plugin, and has a position of -500/out of screen :)
Is it possible to style all input file elements after clone()?
Here is my code :

```
            <table id="table_upld" style="width: 800px;">
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upldfiles_form">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="addcm" type="button" style="width:30px;">+</button>
                    <button class="remcm" type="button" style="width:30px;">-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="upl[]" id="inpcm"/><br /><div class="inpcm2"></div></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="upldfiles_form.submit();">add</button></td>
            </tr>   


        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.addcm').click(function () {
                var clonecm = $('#inpcm').clone(true);
                clonecm.val('');
                clonecm.appendTo('.inpcm2');
            });
            $('.remcm').click(function () {
            $('.inpcm2 input:last-child').remove();
            });
        });
        $(":file").jfilestyle({icon: false});
</script>
```

Comment: see, after you apply the plugin, the file input is not what you're looking at. Cloning in this case will likely be very complicated, i'd suggest not cloning at all, instead simply create a new file input and apply the plugin to only the new input.

Comment: Many plugins do not cope with dynamic content. Others do not cope with an object that already has its attributes, but no code instance. You are better off *plain-cloning* the object and running `fileStyle` against the new element. You may even have to strip attributes that have been added (or clone from a *blank slate* element - in a hidden div etc)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this will be my solution :)